# Lettuce for Python example gives console error?

Tags: python, windows-7, lettuce

Trying to run the simple lettuce tests scenario (from [here](http://pythonhosted.org/lettuce/tutorial/simple.html)).  I get these:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\lettuce-0.2.19-py2.7.egg\lettuce\registry.py", line 88, in call_hook
    callback(*args, **kw)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\lettuce-0.2.19-py2.7.egg\lettuce\plugins\colored_shell_output.py", line 91, in pri
nt_step_ran
    width, height = terminal.get_size()
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\lettuce-0.2.19-py2.7.egg\lettuce\terminal.py", line 24, in get_size
    size = get_terminal_size_win()
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\lettuce-0.2.19-py2.7.egg\lettuce\terminal.py", line 43, in get_terminal_size_win
    res = windll.kernel32.GetConsoleScreenBufferInfo(h, csbi)
ArgumentError: argument 2: <type 'exceptions.TypeError'>: expected LP_CONSOLE_SCREEN_BUFFER_INFO instance instead of c_c
har_Array_22

Died with argument 2: <type 'exceptions.TypeError'>: expected LP_CONSOLE_SCREEN_BUFFER_INFO instance instead of c_char_A
rray_22
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\lettuce-0.2.19-py2.7.egg\lettuce\__init__.py", line 164, in run
    failfast=self.failfast))
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\lettuce-0.2.19-py2.7.egg\lettuce\core.py", line 1186, in run
    scenarios_ran.extend(scenario.run(ignore_case, failfast=failfast))
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\lettuce-0.2.19-py2.7.egg\lettuce\core.py", line 726, in run
    results.append(run_scenario(self, run_callbacks=True))
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\lettuce-0.2.19-py2.7.egg\lettuce\core.py", line 699, in run_scenario
    all_steps, steps_passed, steps_failed, steps_undefined, reasons_to_fail = Step.run_all(self.steps, outline, run_call
backs, ignore_case, failfast=failfast)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\lettuce-0.2.19-py2.7.egg\lettuce\core.py", line 472, in run_all
    call_hook('after_each', 'step', step)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\lettuce-0.2.19-py2.7.egg\lettuce\registry.py", line 88, in call_hook
    callback(*args, **kw)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\lettuce-0.2.19-py2.7.egg\lettuce\plugins\colored_shell_output.py", line 91, in pri
nt_step_ran
    width, height = terminal.get_size()
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\lettuce-0.2.19-py2.7.egg\lettuce\terminal.py", line 24, in get_size
    size = get_terminal_size_win()
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\lettuce-0.2.19-py2.7.egg\lettuce\terminal.py", line 43, in get_terminal_size_win
    res = windll.kernel32.GetConsoleScreenBufferInfo(h, csbi)
ArgumentError: argument 2: <type 'exceptions.TypeError'>: expected LP_CONSOLE_SCREEN_BUFFER_INFO instance instead of c_c
har_Array_22
```

Am I missing some configuration tricks?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
lettuce -v [x]
```

where `x` can be `1, 2 or 3` and specifies the amount of detail shown about the run.

Found the hint here
http://www.erlisvidal.com/2010/10/how-install-lettuce-windows.html

Answer (score 0):

windows haven't fcntl model. 
Edit the file **init**.py located in c:\Python27\Lib\site-packages\lettuce-0.1.20-py2.7.egg\lettuce__init__.py
"In that file locate the line that contains"
in my machine this line appears in line 121 . 
you can replace that line with the line:
from lettuce.plugins import shell_output as output